# How to click on lines in a textarea element

Tags: html, events, click, textarea

I have this textarea element, and i want each line in the box to be clickable and respond to javascript events, is that possible or am i looking for a different type of element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. In order for you do produce such behavior, you would need to design your own "textbox". Google Docs has done this for example, where the entire "textarea" is a complex and highly functional set of divs etc.

Answer (score 0):

A much less intensive version of the multi-div selectable layout could be accomplished with Data Tables.  See the tutorial [here](http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html)

They also offer tutorials on edit-in-place as well as select and delete.  If you're not already using a grid to present data, it's a great tool for UI.